# Manipulacion de fechas en laravel se imprimen en ingles utilizando Carbon formatLocalized

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy mostrando las fechas en mi vista show utilizando Carbon desde el controlador , pero al momento de mostrar en español no se muestran las fechas con dia "miercoles" ni "sabado.

Controlador

```
$tiempo = new Carbon($orden->Fecha_de_Inicio);
    setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es');
    $orden->Fecha_de_Inicio = $tiempo->formatLocalized('%a %d de %B de %Y - %H:%M%p');
```

Vista

```
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="box box-solid box-info" data-widget="box-widget">
                <div class="box-header centrar-texto">
                    Inicio: {{$orden->Fecha_de_Inicio}}
                    <h3 class="box-title">
                    </h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

He probado cambiando el  setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es'); pero siguen sin mostrarse las fechas en el formato que yo necesito.

Mi proyecto esta en local host, al momento de colocar el proyecto en el hosting todas las fechas se muestran en ingles incluso utilizando el  setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es');

Comment: ¿En "local" funcionan las fechas en español?

Answer (score 1):

esta mal organizado

```
//primero inicializa el LC_Time
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es');
$tiempo = new Carbon($orden->Fecha_de_Inicio);
$orden->Fecha_de_Inicio = $tiempo->formatLocalized('%a %d de %B de %Y - %H:%M%p');
```

tambien puede hacer con la funcion estática:

```
Carbon::setLocale('es');
echo Carbon::now()->addYear()->diffForHumans();
```

ademas el error puede venir del sistema:

The probleme come from your system.
para Linux puedes: `locale -a` para activar la lista de locales.

luego puedes `sudo locale-gen id_ID.UTF-8` para instalar y luego `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` para publicarlos.

reinicia el sistema. y veamos que pasa.

Documentación: [link](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization)